# Remove old savegame

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have an old savegame on the iPhone (level 2). Whenever I open the game I started on the iPad Mini (lvl 20), it asks me if I want to load the level 2 village. I tried removing the game from Game Center and the game itself multiple times on the iPhone, but the alert won't go away.

How can I overwrite it with the new save / delete the old one?

Comment: Have you tried wiping the saved game data or restoring the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't alone with these problems.  A [thread here explains it](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/8773-Gamecenter-sync-problem-don-t-want-to-lose-gems), but here is the solution:

> The quote you replied to had an individual who was playing one game
>   locally, signed onto a new device with gamecenter, and basically
>   attached the brand new game to his gamecenter.
>
> So you are left with an old iPhone with your locally played "Good"
>   game, and a new iPhone with a brand new village attached to
>   gamecenter?
>
> You can only have one village attached to gamecenter at a time. If the
>   above is right, then you have 2 options. Create a new gamecenter
>   account and attach it to the good game, or if you want to keep the
>   game on your old gamecenter, there will be extra steps. Either way,
>   you still need to have network capabilities on the old iPhone.
>
> To re-use the old gamecenter currently attached to the new game:
>
> Create brand new gamecenter account Close CoC and log out of
>   gamecenter on the new iPhone. Log into the new iPHone with the brand
>   new gamecenter you just created.  Launch CoC, when prompted to save
>   that village to this new GC, accept. Close CoC, launch it from within
>   the gamecenter app itself, play it for a few minutes, then...
>
> This will have severed the old gamecenter to new village connection.
>
> Go back on the old iPhone and make sure you are logged in with that
>   old gamecenter and launch CoC (good village). This should prompt you
>   to attach that village to the old gamecenter. Same thing, close,
>   launch through gamecenter, play it a few minutes, etc. Close CoC
>
> Next step would be to make sure CoC is closed (force quit it) and you
>   log out of that new gamecenter on the new iPhone. Then log in with the
>   old gamecenter and launch CoC, which will bring the good game over to
>   the new device.

I know when I attached my second iOS device to my gamecenter and launched CoC, it asked me if I wanted to link the village attached to the gamecenter account to this phone.   It will start to walk you through the tutorial, but just go through it until you are on your  own, login to gamecenter and then accept the popup from CoC.